# Which DNS configuration is better for a MX record type?

Tags: dns, bind, opendns, nameserver, dig

*Which DNS configuration is better for a MX record type?*

**1.- Having a single MX reord type mx.domain.com resolving to a two A record type:**

```
MX  10  mail.domain.com.    ->  A   1.1.1.1
                            ->  A   2.2.2.2
```

Or

**2.- Having two MX record type mx1.domain.com. and mx2.domain.com. resolving to A record type.**

```
MX  10  mx1.domain.com.    ->  A   1.1.1.1
MX  20  mx2.domain.com.    ->  A   2.2.2.2
```

What would be the real reason for choosing either option 1 or option 2, currently I have option 1 deployed but I think it is better answer option 2 but I do not know the reason why.

Comment: This may belong on ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

I assume #1 means that the DNS is a round robin between the two hosts.  Given that I'm not sure there is a difference.  But, DNS provided MX weighting (#2) for a reason and I'd be more likely to use #2 over #2.  However, unless you have a reason to prefer one hos over the other, I would recommend a third option

```
MX  10  mx1.domain.com.    ->  A   1.1.1.1
MX  10  mx2.domain.com.    ->  A   2.2.2.2
```

This would route mail through both hosts.  In my experience a failover host is of little value unless it is being used regularly. Otherwise, the configs drift apart and when the backup host is actually needed, it doesn't work.